# Nested loop decrement number

Tags: java, nested-loops

Create a class that asks the user for a number, and then print out the following pattern based on the int input.

So the code I made result looked like this ...

```
12345 
 1234 
  123 
   12
```

But it should look like this

```
    5
   45
  345
 2345
12345
```

```java
Scanner tri = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a postive integer.");
int shape = tri.nextInt();
for(int c = shape; c > 1; --c){
    for (int a = 1; a <= shape-c; a++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int d = 1; d <= c; d++){
        System.out.print(d);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
```

Comment: Your loop printing the numbers of a line always starts at 1 (`for(int d = 1; ...`), so why would you even expect it to print lines starting at a higher number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this code below?

```
Scanner tri = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a postive integer.");
int shape = tri.nextInt();

for (int c = shape; c >= 1; --c) {
    for (int a = 1; a <= c; a++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int d = c; d <= shape; d++) {
        System.out.print(d);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}

// result
//     5 
//    45 
//   345 
//  2345 
// 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a nested loop, you can use some padding. Basically you need to have a string which consists of only spaces and is as long as the number of digits in your number.

In a loop take the substring of your number and fill the remaining with spaces.
My code:

```
public static void pattern(int number)
    {
        String s=Integer.toString(number);
        String padding="";
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++,padding+=" ");
        for(int i=1;i<=s.length();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(padding.substring(i)+s.substring(s.length()-i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am basically formatting it (adding required number of spaces) using the padding.